# Android Studio (Java) I need tips and some answers about skip frames and for loop on a array list

Tags: android-studio

I need tips on 
-1 how to avoid skip frames on my app what scenarios like will lead to skipping frames
-2 If I slow down the speed of for loop on an array-list somehow!. (If you know tell me) add 1 item every 1 sec is it better for no lag? or it's okay to just loop it and let it be?
3- how to make the app much faster even with large queries on SQLite and do things like UI changes and get location requests from google maps and do processes like calculating distance all in the same time if any way else is better to handle all processes please tell me too <3

Comment: usually long and heavy threads are run on AsyncTask.

Comment: Nice, thank you, Any other tips for better like the for loop thing?

Comment: If you are parsing large JSON its better to use GSON library, if you mean any other loop it depends to you how to optimize it. Also its not advisable to have a huge number of loops usually we use pagination to optimize loops.

Comment: Yes yes how to use optimize I mean the name that i can search about on google so i learn more about it ! <3

Comment: Sorry I usually create my own logic in optimization, but I think the term is Pagination Library.

Comment: more or less like this https://guides.codepath.com/android/endless-scrolling-with-adapterviews-and-recyclerview

Comment: Oh thank you I was creating my own too but I'm not sure if it is even good but thank you really, bro, <3